# Laravel Many to many without using id column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables. Players, player_skills and Skills.

```
Players
- bb1_player_id

Skills
- bb1_skill_id

Player_skills
- bb1_player_id
- bb1_skill_id
```

I have created the Player Model with this method.

```
public function skills()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skills', 'player_skills', 'bb1_player_id', 'bb1_skill_id');
}
```

That outputs this Query:

```
"select `skills`.*, `player_skills`.`bb1_player_id` as `pivot_bb1_player_id`, `player_skills`.`bb1_skill_id` as `pivot_bb1_skill_id` from `skills` inner join `player_skills` on `skills`.`id` = `player_skills`.`bb1_skill_id` where `player_skills`.`bb1_player_id` = ?"
```

The query works, but I am hoping to get a query that does not every use the id field of the tables and only uses the fields I am specifying. It uses both the id of the skill and player.id at the '?' of the query. Is there a way around this? Or do I need to rework my tables to conform?

I have also tried adding more options like below to no avail.

```
public function skills()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skills', 'player_skills','bb1_player_id','bb1_skill_id','bb1_player_id','bb1_skill_id');
}
```

Comment: Set the `protected $primaryKey` in your modal according to what Primary Key you want Laravel to use when querying. Set it to `NULL` when you don't want a Primary Key at all.

Comment: What if I want to use this method multiple times on different columns in the table?

Comment: Ultimately I think my best bet is to update Models for each one of these cases. So I can change the primary key.